# PIP is linked only to system environment

Tags: bash, pip, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04, pyenv

I'm using `pyenv-virtualenv` on `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`.

While I was installing `imblearn` package for my virtualenv using `Python 3.5`, I realized it was being installed on `system` environment which uses `Python 2.7`. I checked with `pyenv version` but it clearly returned that I was on my virtualenv.

I opened a Python shell and tried to import `imblearn` and got `ImportError: No module named 'imblearn'`.

When I checked with `pip list`, it clearly stated that `imblearn` was installed. But every other packages that have been installed were missing, hence telling that the list was of `system` environment.

I've tried making a new environment and checked but the list is still of `system` and installation goes to `system` as well.

My `pip` is stuck with `system`.

I have never experienced this before and have no idea how to fix this.

Below is my `.bashrc` setting:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Just the way it tells me to set.

I've been using it fine until yesterday which I found out this was happening.

I suspect it has something to do with `pyenv global` command which I used while I was telling my partner how to use `pyenv-virtualenv` yesterday.

Still, I have never had a problem with that command before.

Please help.

---

**Update**

For some reason, `source ~/.bashrc` put everything back to normal. (I don't know why I typed this command. I just did it.)
But I'd still like to know how this happened and why it is fixed when I changed nothing in my `.bashrc` file and when even re-opening terminal or rebooting didn't fix things.

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as answered sharing your finding with others who will then know that you solved your issue. Please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how this was solved, and assume that this won't happen in later version `pyenv-virtualenv`.

It's a year old post, but I guess I could post what helped me back then so that others won't try to solve my long ago problem for me.

Thanks for letting me know.

`source ~/.bashrc`